# How to convert HWPFDocument to inputstream using POI

Tags: java

I have to change text in doc word and convert to pdf.
I already changed text, but IDK, how to convert HWPFDocument to pdf.

In the call *XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(is);* i get exception **io.IOException: Stream Closed**

```
String inputFilename = "/root/GeneratorUmow/web/WEB-INF/umowy/kkb/wniosekkkb.doc";
POIFSFileSystem fs = null;
is = new FileInputStream(inputFilename);
fs = new POIFSFileSystem(is);
HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);
Range range = doc.getRange();
range.replaceText("nazwaFirmy", "KAKAOWY SZATAN");
//conversion na pdf
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(is);
PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create().fontEncoding("windows-1250");
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("kakaowyszal.pdf"));
PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
```

I will be very grateful for help.

Comment: Which jar file is used for PdfOptions and PdfConverter?

Comment: org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core-1.0.0, org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-1.0.0. Do you have any idea??

Comment: You already add ooxml-lib into your class path?

Comment: yes i attached poi-ooxml-3.5-FINAL

Comment: I mean these three libs. 1) dom4j-1.6.1.jar 2) stax-api-1.0.1.jar 3) xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar.Did you?

Comment: You need to add these 3 jars.

Comment: i think that, this exception is not fault of the missing libraries, but proably POIFSFileSystem has closed the inputStream connection.

Comment: Yeah.I think in case you no need to use POIFSFileSystem.

Comment: what should i do use??

Comment: Your converting case POSFileSystem is extra code.Please delete and test again.

Comment: i can't delete this line of code because i am using it

Comment: You can't reuse a FileInputStream.  You'll need to open a new one for the line `XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(is);`

Answer (score 7):

I know the question is old but there is a simple way to "convert"  XWPFDocument to InputStream. Just in case someone needs it...

```
ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
doc.write(b); // doc should be a XWPFDocument 
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(b.toByteArray());
```